# How to check if program starts from Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a java program that should read an ini file to setup. When starting the program from NetBeans ide the relative path of application points to development folders, while when starting the program from distribution folder the relative path of application is obviously different.

I would like to know how to programmatically check if program starts from NetBeans IDE to correct the path to ini file.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own working directory in netbeans project settings.

[image: Netbeans screenshot]